# Why wavelet transform converts functions into disperse signals?

Tags: reference-request, signal-processing, wavelets

I am studying wavelet transformations and I have read that this type of transformations converts almost any type of functions (including music or images) into disperse signals. I would like to know which is the reason for this fact, so I can better understand when I should apply wavelet transform. Can someone suggest me any paper or material that gives a mathematical proof of this?

Thanks!!